Add Indexes of Array to ArrayList in Java
This is actually for the curiosity. I have attempt to implement a Path Finding algorithm for a certain program.
So Let's say there is an Array Like:
int[][] map = {
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
        };

1 = path, 0 = block
Usually in these cases we are maintaining two ArrayLists as openList, closeList.
What my concern is to store each element we are going to visit as indexes instead of value to ArrayList
ex:- if the (0,1) is visited it will be added as single indexed value to ArrayList; so the first element of list will be (0,1)
openList = [(0,1), (1,0), (2,1), (3,2),...]

If I need to perform this action how can I initialize my arraylist. because in this case ArrayList <Integer> openList; type of list cannot be used.
